# Optimizing function computation in a pandas column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nlp, treetagger

Let's assume that I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
id |opinion
1  |Hi how are you?
...
n-1|Hello!
```

I would like to create a new pandas [POS-tagged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) column like this:

```
id|     opinion   |POS-tagged_opinions
1 |Hi how are you?|hi\tUH\thi
                  how\tWRB\thow
                  are\tVBP\tbe
                  you\tPP\tyou
                  ?\tSENT\t?

.....

n-1|     Hello    |Hello\tUH\tHello
                   !\tSENT\t!
```

From the documentation a tutorial, I tried several approaches. Particularly:

```
df.apply(postag_cell, axis=1)
```

and

```
df['content'].map(postag_cell)
```

Therefore, I created this POS-tag cell function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/user/Desktop/data2.csv', sep='|')
print df.head()


def postag_cell(pandas_cell):
    import pprint   # For proper print of sequences.
    import treetaggerwrapper
    tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')
    #2) tag your text.
    y = [i.decode('UTF-8') if isinstance(i, basestring) else i for i in [pandas_cell]]
    tags = tagger.tag_text(y)
    #3) use the tags list... (list of string output from TreeTagger).
    return tags



#df.apply(postag_cell(), axis=1)

#df['content'].map(postag_cell())




df['POS-tagged_opinions'] = (df['content'].apply(postag_cell))

print df.head()
```

The above function return the following:

```
user:~/PycharmProjects/misc_tests$ time python tagging\ with\ pandas.py



id|     opinion   |POS-tagged_opinions
1 |Hi how are you?|[hi\tUH\thi
                  how\tWRB\thow
                  are\tVBP\tbe
                  you\tPP\tyou
                  ?\tSENT\t?]

.....

n-1|     Hello    |Hello\tUH\tHello
                   !\tSENT\t!

--- 9.53674316406e-07 seconds ---

real    18m22.038s
user    16m33.236s
sys 1m39.066s
```

The problem is that with large number of [opinions](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5bowh8tzff91fvd/new_corpus.csv) it get takes a lot of time:

**How to perform pos-tagging more efficiently and in a more pythonic way with pandas and treetagger?**. I believe that this issue is due my pandas limited knowledge, since I tagged very quickly the opinions just with treetagger, out of a pandas dataframe.

Comment: The first thing to do is moving the first three lines from the definition of `postag_cell` (two `import`'s and `tagger=...`) outside the function body. It's enough to call them once (and they may seriously slow down the code). BTW, the github link to "opinions" doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ptrj, I updated the question with the opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some obvious modifications that can be done to gain a reasonable amount of time (as removing the imports and the instantiation of TreeTagger class from `postag_cell` function). Then the code can be parallelized. However, the majority of work is done by treetagger itself. As I don't know anything about this software, I can't tell if it can be further optimized.

### The minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import treetaggerwrapper

input_file = 'new_corpus.csv'
output_file = 'output.csv'

def postag_string(s):
    '''Returns tagged text from string s'''
    if isinstance(s, basestring):
       s = s.decode('UTF-8')
    return tagger.tag_text(s)

# Reading in the file
all_lines = []
with open(input_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        all_lines.append(line.strip().split('|', 1))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_lines[1:], columns = all_lines[0])

tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')

df['POS-tagged_content'] = df['content'].apply(postag_string)

# Format fix:
def fix_format(x):
    '''x - a list or an array'''
    # With encoding:
    out = list(tuple(i.encode().split('\t')) for i in x)
    # or without:
    # out = list(tuple(i.split('\t')) for i in x)
    return out
df['POS-tagged_content'] = df['POS-tagged_content'].apply(fix_format)

df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')
```

I'm not using `pd.read_csv(filename, sep = '|')` because your input file is "misformatted" - it contains unescaped characters `|` in some text opinions.

(**Update:**) After format fix, the output file looks like this:

```
$ cat output_example.csv 
|id|content|POS-tagged_content
0|cv01.txt|How are you?|[('How', 'WRB', 'How'), ('are', 'VBP', 'be'), ('you', 'PP', 'you'), ('?', 'SENT', '?')]
1|cv02.txt|Hello!|[('Hello', 'UH', 'Hello'), ('!', 'SENT', '!')]
2|cv03.txt|"She said ""OK""."|"[('She', 'PP', 'she'), ('said', 'VVD', 'say'), ('""', '``', '""'), ('OK', 'UH', 'OK'), ('""', ""''"", '""'), ('.', 'SENT', '.')]"
```

If the formatting is not exactly what you want, we can work it out.

### Parallelized code

It may give some speedup but don't expect miracles. The overhead coming from multiprocess setting may even exceed the gains. You can experiment with the number of processes `nproc` (here, set by default to number of CPUs; setting more than this is inefficient).

Treetaggerwrapper has its own multiprocess [class](http://treetaggerwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#polls-of-taggers-threads). I suspect that it does more less the same thing as the code below, so I didn't try it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import treetaggerwrapper
import multiprocessing as mp

input_file = 'new_corpus.csv'
output_file = 'output2.csv'

def postag_string_mp(s):
    '''
    Returns tagged text for string s.
    "pool_tagger" is a global name, defined in each subprocess.
    '''
    if isinstance(s, basestring):
       s = s.decode('UTF-8')
    return pool_tagger.tag_text(s)

''' Reading in the file '''
all_lines = []
with open(input_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        all_lines.append(line.strip().split('|', 1))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_lines[1:], columns = all_lines[0])

''' Multiprocessing '''

# Number of processes can be adjusted for better performance:
nproc = mp.cpu_count()

# Function to be run at the start of every subprocess.
# Each subprocess will have its own TreeTagger called pool_tagger.
def init():
    global pool_tagger
    pool_tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')

# The actual job done in subprcesses:
def run(df):
    return df.apply(postag_string_mp)

# Splitting the input
lst_split = np.array_split(df['content'], nproc)

pool = mp.Pool(processes = nproc, initializer = init)
lst_out = pool.map(run, lst_split)
pool.close()
pool.join()

# Concatenating the output from subprocesses 
df['POS-tagged_content'] =  pd.concat(lst_out) 

# Format fix:
def fix_format(x):
    '''x - a list or an array'''
    # With encoding:
    out = list(tuple(i.encode().split('\t')) for i in x)
    # and without:
    # out = list(tuple(i.split('\t')) for i in x)
    return out
df['POS-tagged_content'] = df['POS-tagged_content'].apply(fix_format)

df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')
```

**Update**

In Python 3, all strings are by default in unicode, so you can save some trouble and time with decoding/encoding. (In the code below, I also use pure numpy arrays instead of data frames in child processes - but the impact of this change is insignificant.)

```
# Python3 code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import treetaggerwrapper
import multiprocessing as mp

input_file = 'new_corpus.csv'
output_file = 'output3.csv'

''' Reading in the file '''
all_lines = []
with open(input_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        all_lines.append(line.strip().split('|', 1))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_lines[1:], columns = all_lines[0])

''' Multiprocessing '''

# Number of processes can be adjusted for better performance:
nproc = mp.cpu_count()

# Function to be run at the start of every subprocess.
# Each subprocess will have its own TreeTagger called pool_tagger.
def init():
    global pool_tagger
    pool_tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='en')

# The actual job done in subprcesses:
def run(arr):
    out = np.empty_like(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        out[i] = pool_tagger.tag_text(arr[i])
    return out

# Splitting the input
lst_split = np.array_split(df.values[:,1], nproc)

with mp.Pool(processes = nproc, initializer = init) as p:
    lst_out = p.map(run, lst_split)

# Concatenating the output from subprocesses 
df['POS-tagged_content'] =  np.concatenate(lst_out) 

# Format fix:
def fix_format(x):
    '''x - a list or an array'''
    out = list(tuple(i.split('\t')) for i in x)
    return out
df['POS-tagged_content'] = df['POS-tagged_content'].apply(fix_format)

df.to_csv(output_file, sep = '|')
```

After single runs (so, not really statistically significant), I'm getting these timings on your file:

```
$ time python2.7 treetagger_minimal.py 
real    0m59.783s
user    0m50.697s
sys     0m16.657s

$ time python2.7 treetagger_mp.py   
real    0m48.798s
user    1m15.503s
sys     0m22.300s

$ time python3 treetagger_mp3.py 
real    0m39.746s
user    1m25.340s
sys     0m21.157s
```

If the only use of pandas dataframe `pd` is to save everything back to a file, then the next step would be removing pandas from the code at all. But again, the gain would be insignificant in comparison with treetagger's work time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. With regards to `POS-tagged_content` column currently the content is in a list like this: `['How\tWRB\tHow', 'are\tVBP\tbe', 'you\tPP\tyou', '?\tSENT\t?']`, is there anyway to format such column in a more "parseable" way like tuples: `[(How, WRB, How), (are, VBP, be),(you, PP, you), (?,SENT,?)` ?.

Comment: @ml_student Sure, it is. I'll fix it in a sec.

Comment: @ml_student Updated. Hope, this is what you want.